# Problem Running Omnet simulation (exit code 1)

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet, lte

I'm trying to run a simulation in OMNeT++. I started my own project which references veins, inet, and lte. I've copied their examples modifying the .ned packages to test the project setting. About four days ago I was able to run all the examples. After that I modified and created NED files and their definition on .cc and .h, however the files that I created are new and they are not referenced by the simulations that I copied.

When trying to run the simulations in both Qtenv and Cmdenv without any success. I've get the following error:

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OButV.png)

I also have the following configurations:

[Makemake options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOuKZ.png)

[Makemake options 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYtoS.png)

If you could give me any insights about the problem and how to solve it I would be really thankful. If you could also give me some insights on how to avoid problems in running simulations (I've delete my workspace previously to solve some problems) I would be also thanksful.

Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was in the method MessageGenerator::handleLowerMessage (as said on the last line of the error). I have declared it on .h but not implemented it on .cc.

I wrote an empty method in .cc and that's it.